# WPF - Determine if dynamically created control would fit a container

Tags: wpf

Having dynamically created control is there a way to check if it would fit in a container like a grid's column with specified `MaxWidth`?

My current solution is to add the control to the container, wait for layout update then check if that control's total width is greater than the container's width.

```
//Code inside Window's metod

var checkbox = new CheckBox
{
    Content = "Some content"
};
ButtonBarOption.Children.Add(checkbox);

UpdateLayout();

if (ButtonBarOption.ActualWidth > ButtonBarOptionColumn.MaxWidth)
{
    ButtonBarOption.Children.Remove(checkbox);
    OptionsContainer.Children.Add(checkbox);
}
```

Like in the example above when the control don't fit the container I'm relocating it to different place.

Comment: Is it definitely necessary for the container to have a fixed width?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes it is.

Comment: What do you do if the content won't fit in the grid column? Just tell the user they're out of luck?

Comment: It is included in the post. However I think it's not necessary information to solve my issue.

Comment: What you need to is measure.  See answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401636/measuring-controls-created-at-runtime-in-wpf .  You still need to add the control to the container.  But this is the best you can do because otherwise you would have to duplicate all the layout calculations.